# Have problem with Query with EXISTS and IN operator in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have items and tags table, which have many-to-many connection, I'm trying to select all items records, and set custom boolean field with true value if item have tag with some name, false otherwise.

Example:

```
SELECT *, EXISTS(
      SELECT id, text FROM tags
      INNER JOIN "itemsTags" ON "itemsTags"."itemId"=item.id AND "itemsTags"."tagId"=tags.id
      WHERE text IN ('orcs', 'lol')) AS "hasTag" FROM "items" AS "item"
```

When I set only one value in IN operator it selects correctly and only one item record have true value, but if i set more, all records have true value.

And it doesn't matters exists the second value or not in the tags table.

I tried the next example, but result is the same

```
SELECT *, EXISTS(
      SELECT * FROM tags
      INNER JOIN "itemsTags" ON "itemsTags"."itemId"=item.id AND "itemsTags"."tagId"=tags.id
      WHERE tags.text IN ('orcs', 'lol')) AS "hasTag" FROM "items" AS "item"
```

With the next query I selects all records and add extra fields coincidingTagsExists and coincidingTagsAmount. First extra field shows is there related tag exists, second - amount of tags relevant to query text: ogre or planet.

```
SELECT *, EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM tags INNER JOIN "itemsTags" ON "itemsTags"."itemId"=item.id AND "itemsTags"."tagId"=tags.id
        WHERE tags.text IN ('ogre','planet')
      ) as "coincidingTagsExists", (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tags INNER JOIN "itemsTags" ON "itemsTags"."itemId"=item.id AND "itemsTags"."tagId"=tags.id
      WHERE tags.text IN ('ogre','planet')) as "coincidingTags" FROM "items" AS "item"
```

As I work with sequelize result was an array of objects, as we can see even when coincidingTagsAmount equals to 0, coincidingTagsExists fields still have true value:

```
{
  id: 21,
  name: 'shrek',
  coincidingTagsExists: true,
  coincidingTagsAmount: '1'
},
{
  id: 23,
  name: 'planet',
  coincidingTagsExists: true,
  coincidingTagsAmount: '1'
},
{
  id: 24,
  name: 'knight',
  coincidingTagsExists: true,
  coincidingTagsAmount: '0'
},
{
  id: 25,
  name: 'PolarMan',
  coincidingTagsExists: true,
  coincidingTagsAmount: '0'
}
```

But if I set in IN operator only ogre(`...WHERE tags.text IN ('ogre')...`), the result will be next:

```
{
  id: 21,
  name: 'shrek',
  coincidingTagsExists: true,
  coincidingTagsAmount: '1'
},
{
  id: 23,
  name: 'planet',
  coincidingTagsExists: false,
  coincidingTagsAmount: '0'
},
{
  id: 24,
  name: 'knight',
  coincidingTagsExists: false,
  coincidingTagsAmount: '0'
},
{
  id: 25,
  name: 'PolarMan',
  coincidingTagsExists: false,
  coincidingTagsAmount: '0'
}
```

Comment: The subquery doesn't seem correlated with the outer query, so it should always return the same values, unless `text` is a column of `items`. Please clarify by qualifying *all* column references with the table name.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe,I recreate my query as I understand and added it to the text above, but it still doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, your subquery is independent from the outer query, so it must yield the same value for all rows of `items`. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm trying to query all records from items table, and insert into each record boolean custom field, which should show does this item have related tag with text field value equals to query, in my case:"orcs","lol"

Comment: What is missing is the "related". You have to write a subquery that refers to the current row in `items` in some way.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I just can't understand why this query works correctly when there is only one tag text in IN operator, if i set only "orcs" for example it works well

Comment: It won't work correctly with a single tag in `IN`, not unless you also change something else.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe but I checked it by myself, it worked

Comment: So you claim, but I don't believe you. Please show that second statement. Ideally, add a reproducible test case to the question (with object definitions and data). This should not be a discussion about believes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Added the example above